# HTML navbar header width

Tags: html, css, django

I have a Django project using navbar class in base.html as the following.

```
<body>
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" 
              data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'xx:index' %}">Introduction</a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="{% url 'xx:topics' %}">Start search</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'xx:results' %}">Search results</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          Hello, {{ user.username }}
          <a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">log out</a>
        {% else %}
          <a href="{% url 'users:register' %}">register</a>
          <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">log in</a>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

In one web page, the content page is over the default width. But when I scroll the x-axix to the right. The navbar header do not extends to the left and there is some blank as the figure below. How could I adjust the base.html code to let the navbar extend to the left?

[image]

Comment: did you try nav { width:100%; }

Comment: nav {width: 100vw;}

Comment: I'm sorry. May I know where could I add such nav {width: 100vw;}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a css problem try adding this to your css file:

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Dirty way (not recommended):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="width:100%">
```

Or inside your head tags

```
<head>
  <style>
      nav {
        width: 100%
      }
  </style>
</head>
```

Also I recommend watching a little css/html tutorials. If you are suing bootstrap 
makes sure you have a similar structuri inside your nav: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

I don't like the `<div class="container"></div>` inside your `<nav>`

**Update (dirty fix):**

Add to your css:

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This is not a good fix, you should learn a little more about how css and html works and try to re-structure your page. We cannot help you because we have no idea whats going on in your css and the rest of your page - something is taking up the space on the right. You can spot it easily in chrome and firefox with the inspect element tool.

Comment: Thx! but where should I add it?

Comment: Best practice is adding a css file and linking it to your html page using <link> tag.
If you just want to get it done the dirty way just add attribute style="nav{width:100%}" to your nav tag.

Comment: If you don't have a .css file that you include inside your <head> tags then put my code in the head tag inside <style> tags.

Comment: you are using bootstrap?

Comment: Try removing the <div class="container"></div> inside the <nav>

Comment: Yes. After removing the container. It still have the blank on the right.

Comment: this is a dirty fix, add to your css this: body {overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;}
I updated my answer.